# Groupby with max on string dtype and keep all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to group by `DocumentNo` and return the `Max` of the `Concat` column. However I want the `Revision` column (any other columns I add to this df) to be included in final output.

This is an example input:

```
DocumentNo                 Revision  Concat
MAOIE-2100-CI-MTO-0001     4         MAOIE-2100-CI-MTO-00014
MAOIE-5100-EL-MTO-0005     3         MAOIE-5100-EL-MTO-00053
MAOIE-2100-CI-MTO-0001     5         MAOIE-2100-CI-MTO-00015
```

This should be the output:

```
DocumentNo                 Revision  Concat
MAOIE-5100-EL-MTO-0005     3         MAOIE-5100-EL-MTO-00053
MAOIE-2100-CI-MTO-0001     5         MAOIE-2100-CI-MTO-00015
```

I've tried this but I get an `argmax` error I think because `Concat` is a string column.

```
df = df.groupby(['DocumentNo'], as_index=False).agg({'Concat': 'max', 'Revision': 'first'})
```

This works, but only returns the `DocumentNo` and `Concat` columns:

```
df = df.groupby('DocumentNo')['Concat'].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
df.groupby("DocumentNo").apply(lambda d:d.loc[d["Concat"]==d["Concat"].max()])
```

Probably a faster way exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `merge()` after find the `groupby.max()`

```py
out = df.merge(df.groupby('DocumentNo', as_index=False)['Concat'].max())
```

```
print(out)

               DocumentNo  Revision                   Concat
0  MAOIE-5100-EL-MTO-0005         3  MAOIE-5100-EL-MTO-00053
1  MAOIE-2100-CI-MTO-0001         5  MAOIE-2100-CI-MTO-00015
```

Comment: Ahh okay. So is this basically just performing an inner join between existing dataframe, and output of groupby - joining by DocumentNo and Concat?

Comment: @AaronWright Yes.